# Running python with PowerShell in Power Automate Desktop

Tags: python, powershell

I am trying to run a python code through PowerShell in Power Automate Desktop. Inside of the python code I have few lines to create a text file and save it into my computer. I have run the code in Visual  Code, Windows PowerShell and Command Prompt and it runs perfectly. However, when I try to call the same python code through "Run PowerShell Script" in Power Automate Desktop, it does not create the file at all, therefore I am not getting any output.

The difference is that I type manually the arguments in Visual Code:

> C:\Users\my name> & "C:\Users\my name\anaconda3\python.exe"
> "C:\Users\my name\Desktop\test\Script_for_PAD.py" "New York" "Brand"
> "Nike"

... while in Power Automate Desktop, when I run the same code with PowerShell option, I call the arguments by calling variables that a user has introduced in the input dialog in previous steps in the flow:

> & "C:\Users\my name\anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Users\my
> name\Desktop\test\Script_for_PAD.py" "%City%" "%Search%"
> "%Brand%"

.... so the user had options to select which city, brand... they are looking for, and after this, the PowerShell will run the python code with these arguments.

As the code works well in Windows PowerShell, I wonder if the problem is with Power Automate Desktop as it is not creating the text file I ordered inside the python code or if I am doing something wrong when calling the arguments... I have also checked all the environments and I am using the same python for all of them....

Can anyone help me to understand this a bit better please???

Comment: could it be that it is not executing as a PYTHON file in the Power Automat Desktop?  you said powershell option so it may be calling it as a powershell script and not a python script?

Comment: What I am trying to do is calling the path to the python script in the powershell option in Power Automate Desktop. So I am expecting that once I call the path, it will execute the python code. I tried with a very simple code like "print ("Hello world") and it worked fine, so I guess I can run the python script through the powershell